# Удаление лишних записей из таблицы Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Здравствуйте. Есть надобность очищать таблицу от лишних записей с `xml` файлами. Нужно сделать вот как.

Если в таблице есть уже 10 записей. И добавляется 11 тогда нужно удалить самую старую. В принципе это можно делать по первичному ключу. Строка с самым маленьким первичным ключом удаляется.

Это наверно удобней всего сделать тригером. Но проблема в том что не разу не работал с тригерами и не знаю как их писать. Не могли бы кто нибудь подкинуть вариант тригера для моего случая. Буду очень благодарен. Вот название таблицы и поля первичного ключа: `TRANSFER_TABLE`, `TRANSFER_TABLE_ID` соответственно.

Спасибо заранее.

Comment: @Mike помогите пожалуйста если сможете с этим вопросом.

Comment: @Андрей помогите пожалуйста если сможете с этим вопросом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create trigger TRANSFER_TABLE_DEL_OLD after insert on TRANSFER_TABLE
 begin
  delete from TRANSFER_TABLE
   where TRANSFER_TABLE_ID<=(
    select max(TRANSFER_TABLE_ID)
      from (
        select TRANSFER_TABLE_ID,row_number() over(order by TRANSFER_TABLE_ID desc) RN
          from TRANSFER_TABLE
      )
    where RN>10
   );
 end;
/
```

Comment: большое спасибо. Всё прекрасно работает. Очень вам благодарен за помощь.